# C# Initializing in the constructor not working

Tags: c#, class, version-control, constructor, initialization

I have a property that checks if Version Contorl is null. If it's null, the version control's value is set with `tpc.GetService<VersionControlServer>();`. The problem is that, it still returns null even if I set it.

```
private VersionControlServer versionControl;

public VersionControlServer VersionControl
{
    get 
    {
    return this.versionControl; 
    }   
    set 
    {
        if (versionControl == null)
        {
        this.versionControl = this.tpc.GetService<VersionControlServer>();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Um, when you wrote the code to initialize `this.versionControl`, you put in the `set` handler. Therefore, it doesn't run during a `get`. (Also, your `set` handler doesn't use the `value`, which makes it not really a setter.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have your null check in the wrong place. You should have it in the `get` and initialize it there.

You also seems to be reintialising it every time you set it. Maybe you should use the `value` when you set it? You can remove it (the `set` that is) but that makes this property `readonly`.

```
public VersionControlServer VersionControl
{
   get 
   {
      if (versionControl == null)
      {
        this.versionControl = this.tpc.GetService<VersionControlServer>();
      }

      return this.versionControl; 
   }   
   set 
   {
     this.versionControl = value;   
   }
}
```

Comment: Nope. I use the property in a method and it says that it cannot be assigned because it's readonly

Comment: @user2379805 Then do not remove the `set` put it back in like it is in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

It will be `null` until you set its value (so that your `set` accessor is called).

You should just change it to this (ignoring possible threading issues):

```
public VersionControlServer VersionControl
{
    get 
    {
        if (versionControl == null)
        {
            this.versionControl = this.tpc.GetService<VersionControlServer>();
        }

        return this.versionControl; 
    }   
}
```

You don't need a `set` for this property.. since you never bother to use `value`.

Comment: Thanks. I also tried you solution but I cannot assign it in a method because it makes the property readonly.

Comment: Your property is already readonly.. you never use `value` in your "setter".